# Find all x and y that make the equation $y(x^2 + y^2 + 1) + 2(3xy + 2) = 2005$ true

Tags: calculus

The question says: Find all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ that make $y(x^2 + y^2 + 1) + 2(3xy + 2) = 2005$ true.

At first I've simplified the expression:
$$x^2y + y^3 + y + 6xy = 2001$$
$$y(x^2 + y^2 + y + 6xy + 1) = 2001$$

Then I've made prime factorization of $2001$
$$2001 = 3 \cdot 23 \cdot 29$$
$$2001 = 3 \cdot 667$$
$$2001 = 69 \cdot 29$$
$$2001 = 87 \cdot 23$$

And I've checked every possible variant (6 variants) with $y$. Nothing matches. So is the answer that there are no such $x$ and $y$?

Edit: the question doesn't mention that $x$ and $y$ are integers

p.s. English is not my native language so sorry if there are grammar mistakes.

Comment: Independent of English, are we looking for integer solutions? Or positive integer solutions? Or real ones?

Comment: The question doesn't mention it, so real ones

Comment: Over integers there are no solutions, in case it will be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y=0$ is impossible, the equation is equivalent to the quadratic equation
$$
x^2 + 6x + y^2 + 1 - \frac{2001}{y}=0
$$
This has two real solutions, by the usual formula, if and only if
$$ 
- y^4 + 8y^2 + 2001y \ge 0.
$$
hence the equation has infinitely many real solutions. For example, take $y=1$ and $x=\pm 2 \sqrt{502} - 3$, and then $y=1+\epsilon$ with infinitely many small $\epsilon \in [0,1]$.